# Coleman CT200u problems after upgrades

Tags: clutch, throttle

I recently installed a ARC billet rod, dyno cam, new flywheel, new valve springs. After installing all of it, now when i start the bike, it sounds and runs fine with the choke on, as soon as I take the choke off the bike just takes off, full throttle. I removed the throttle cable and it still just tries to go. Ive tried holding the throttle plate back so there is essentially no way it should be taking off, but still it tries to go. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!